# Decimal conversion

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to set decimal values,Below is my input string

```
String rate="1.000000000";
```

Converting to double:

```
Double converted=Double.valueOf(rate);
DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#.########"); //Setting decimal points to 8

System.out.println("ouput"+format.format(rate)); //Giving output as 1.
```

I dont understand how to do this,Any hints please.

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: Next time, please really comment the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");
```

and

```
System.out.println("ouput"+format.format(converted));
```

Comment: @user see my edit. you'll have to use the var `converted` in `format()`. See http://ideone.com/El29N

Answer (score 4):

`#` will not be displayed for 0, use `0` instead:

```
    String rate="1.010000000";
    Double converted=Double.valueOf(rate);
    DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("0.00000000");       
    System.out.println("ouput "+format.format(converted));
```

Comment: @sthupahsmaht - I posted before I saw Bala's edit (regarding `converted`)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're passing the string `rate` to the `DecimalFormat.format` method.  This will fail, you need to pass the `converted` object in.

When I tested your code with the above changes, I got 1.01 in the output.  To format to 8 decimal places, follow Bala Rs comments.  i.e. `DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");`